# Difference between 俺物語 and 俺の物語

Tags: word-choice, compounds

There is an anime/manga  called  俺物語!! which is translated as "My Story!!" or "My Love Story!!" depending on which site you visit. The way I have learned it, it should be "俺の物語" to be "my story" instead of the "俺物語". My question is: What is the difference between "俺物語" and  "俺の物語"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「俺物語」 is named in accordance with a typical name for stories, (noun)物語. The most famous of these would be 「源氏物語」. 俺の物語 would simply be 'a story of mine'. An interesting note about these 物語 titles: the Japanese translation of *The Lord of the Rings* is called 「指輪物語」.